# How to retrieve the namespace in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, namespaces, laravel-5.6

I changed the namespace from `App` to `SAMM` by using command `php artisan app:name` in Laravel 5.6, but now an error is shown:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class SAMM\Http\Kernel does
not exist in
/home/vagrant/sites/SAM/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php
on line 767
```

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you **really** change the namespace everywhere, including all your classes and the paths to them?

Comment: This one I not sure .. , is there any way to retrieve it ?

Comment: Yes, check where your files are placed and whether the namespace is given properly

Comment: Thanks for reply..but i found the solution ady..because i need to autoload the composer using command `composer dump-autoload`. So the composer can read the new namespace